# Enabling Parallelization in Spark with Partition Pushdown in MemSQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, singlestore

I have a columnstore table in MemSQL that has a schema similar the one below:

```
CREATE TABLE key_metrics (
source_id TEXT,
date TEXT,
metric1 FLOAT,
metric2 FLOAT,
…
SHARD KEY (source_id, date) USING CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE
);
```

I have a Spark application (running with Spark Job Server) that queries the MemSQL table. Below is a simplified form of the kind of Dataframe operation I am doing (in Scala):

```
sparkSession
.read
.format(“com.memsql.spark.connector”)
.options( Map (“path” -> “dbName.key_metrics”))
.load()
.filter(col(“source_id”).equalTo(“12345678”)
.filter(col(“date”)).isin(Seq(“2019-02-01”, “2019-02-02”, “2019-02-03”))
```

I have confirmed by looking at the physical plan that these filter predicates are being pushed down to MemSQL.

I have  also checked that there is a pretty even distribution of the partitions in the table:

```
±--------------±----------------±-------------±-------±-----------+
| DATABASE_NAME | TABLE_NAME | PARTITION_ID | ROWS | MEMORY_USE |
±--------------±----------------±-------------±-------±-----------+
| dbName        | key_metrics |           0 | 784012 |        0 |
| dbName        | key_metrics |           1 | 778441 |        0 |
| dbName        | key_metrics |           2 | 671606 |        0 |
| dbName        | key_metrics |           3 | 748569 |        0 |
| dbName        | key_metrics |           4 | 622241 |        0 |
| dbName        | key_metrics |           5 | 739029 |        0 |
| dbName        | key_metrics |           6 | 955205 |        0 |
| dbName        | key_metrics |           7 | 751677 |        0 |
±--------------±----------------±-------------±-------±-----------+
```

My question is regarding partition pushdown. It is my understanding that with it, we can use all the cores of the machines and leverage parallelism for bulk loading. According to the docs, this is done by creating as many Spark tasks as there are MemSQL database partitions.

However when running the Spark pipeline and observing the Spark UI, it seems that there is only one Spark task that is created which makes a single query to the DB that runs on a single core.

I have made sure that the following properties are set as well:

```
spark.memsql.disablePartitionPushdown = false
```

```
spark.memsql.defaultDatabase = “dbName”
```

Is my understanding of partition pushdown incorrect? Is there some other configuration that I am missing?

Would appreciate your input on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Singlestore credentials have to be the same on all nodes to take advantage of partition pushdown.

And if you have same credentials thru out all the nodes please try installing latest version of spark connector.

Because it often occurs due to spark connector and singlestore compatibility issues.